# multipart/form-data File upload request from Flash to GAE misses data

Tags: python, flash, google-app-engine, http

I have a google app engine request handler that processes multipart/form-data request from file uploads. It works fine with a html form but with the flash uploader it seems that no parameters are passed through.

Here is the data I have put together:

https://gist.github.com/martinheidegger/b8ee4982eb9580b9baa9

It contains the two http requests, one working, one broken together with the log output for logging.info("%s" % self.request.POST);

What am I missing? Why does the flash request not "arrive" at the GAE?

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving the POST request but missing all the POST data?
It could be due to the HTTP headers were not sent properly in Flash.
Try to read and parse directly from the HTTP request body and you should get something.

Comment: It seems like there was a problem in the Flash code. I used a different library and it worked out. I wonder thought what the problem with the above mentioned http request was...